# Invalid Delegation Token. Invalid national Cloud ID (1) is specified

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, office365, azure-active-directory

We have an O365 tenant, everything is configured out of the box. The tenant is placed in the German cloud and not in global (office.de).
We also developed an Office Add-in that authorize access to sharepoint using OAuth 2.0.
First, we initiate a request for a code to this url:

```
http://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=client_id&redirect_uri=redirect_uri&state=state
```

and we get all values back including the code.
Then, we initiate a request for the Discovery Service to discover the services using this url:

```
https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token?client_id=client_id&redirect_uri=redirect_uri&resource=https://api.office.com/discovery/&grant_type=authorization_code&code=code
```

In the global cloud everything is ok and we get the list of services we need but in the German cloud we get the following error:

> {
>     "error": "invalid_grant",
>     "error_description": "AADSTS90051: Invalid Delegation Token. Invalid national Cloud ID (1) is specified.\r\nTrace ID: 52f8aa2b-9f98-4ba6-b778-c0ba484a3c00\r\nCorrelation ID: 67100192-82c8-41ea-a5ca-fd9872caaf2e\r\nTimestamp: 2018-02-08 06:31:18Z",
>     "error_codes": [
>       90051
>     ],
>     "timestamp": "2018-02-08 06:31:18Z",
>     "trace_id": "52f8aa2b-9f98-4ba6-b778-c0ba484a3c00",
>     "correlation_id": "67100192-82c8-41ea-a5ca-fd9872caaf2e"
>   }

The same error occurs when we try to change the url to `https://login.windows.de/common/oauth2/token`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use **client crendetials flow** to achieve that:

1.Request the access token for the Office Discovery service API:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.de/{{yourtenantId}}/oauth2/token?client_id={{client_id}}&client_secret={{client_secret}}&grant_type=client_credentials&resource=https://api.office.com/discovery/
```

2.Use the access token in the head and use the Office Discovery API:

[image]

**Additional**: If you want to get `id_token` and use it, try to use `https://login.microsoftonline.de` as the AAD Athorization endpoint in your request. I didn't test, but it should work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Shouldn't it be POST to `https://login.microsoftonline.de/{{yourtenantId}}/oauth2/token` with `client_id={{client_id}}&client_secret={{client_secret}}&grant_type=client_credentials&resource=https://api.office.com/discovery/` as the form content? :) Now it's in the query.

Comment: @juunas I know what you mean. But the `Body` is following `?`. So, they are same request.

Comment: To use this flow we need to install an azure application in the customer's azure ad and they need to give us a tenantid and a secret.
We also give up the login process.